# android OnItemLongClickListener listview to display listview checkboxes

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I would like to create an android app which displays a list in a listview and then allow the user to delete an item when on onItemlongclick and then displays checkboxes to select which items to delete.

I know it have to call the OnItemLongClickListener but do not know how to implement that. Any ideas to do this?

```
 lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

 @Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    return false;
}
```

I'm so lost in ideas how to do this. I googled but unfortunately didn't find any relevant tutorials.
Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Its all about using the signature of the onItemLongClick-method properly. For instance int pos is the groupposition of the clicked list-item.

Comment: You've got two questions.  The first appears to be how to respond to the item click.  See my answer below.  If you need help with the second - how to delete - I suggest you post a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this just recently, but it was an ad hoc fix, so this might not be the best way.

In the layout for my ListView items (rows), I included a CheckBox whose visibility will be toggled, but is initially not visible, i.e., `View.GONE`.
Then, in my Adapter, I included a member boolean variable, `selectable`, and a public method to set it and refresh:

```
private boolean selectable = false;

public void setSelectable(boolean selectable)
{
    this.selectable = selectable;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In the `getView()` method of the Adapter, `selectable` is checked and the CheckBox's visibility is set accordingly.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ...
    cbx.setVisibility(selectable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    ...
}
```

I used a ToggleButton to change the selection mode, but in your case, you'll need to do something a little different. I would add an additional method to the Adapter:

```
public boolean isSelectable()
{
    return selectable;
}
```

Then, you can toggle the selectable state on long clicks:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id)
{
    ...
    yourAdapter.setSelectable(!yourAdapter.isSelectable);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To respond to clicks on list items, you need to put this in onCreate():

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list);
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener (this);
lv.setLongClickable (true);
```

Then, onItemLongClickListener will be called whenever the user long-touches a list item.  Put a breakpoint there and be satisfied you understand this much.

Comment: THanks but I already did this, what I want to do is to display the checkboxes in the listview